# leaflet count by featuretypes in featuregroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there any way in leaflet to get the number of rectangles in a feature group?
I know this code that work: `drawnItems.getLayers().length;` but it counts all the objects within the drawnItems featuregroup. I only need the a specific type of features, for example `rectangle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using instances of `L.Rectangle`, you can use functional programming like so:

```
drawnItems.getLayers().filter( function(l) {return l instanceof L.Rectangle} ).length;
```

The [`filter` method of `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will return another array, containing only the elements which make the callback function return true; in this case, it will return an array containing only those layers which are instances of `L.Rectangle`.

Comment: instanceof instead isntanceof :) minor spelling mistake