# leaflet remove a specific type of features from featuregroup

Tags: leaflet

Is there any way in leaflet to delete  a specific type of features from a feature group (mixed content: markers, polygons, polylines)? I know this code that work: `map.removeLayer(drawnItems);` but it delete all the objects within the drawnItems featuregroup. I only need a specific type of features, for example all the markers to be deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a similar way to my answer to [leaflet count by featuretypes in featuregroup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244678/leaflet-count-by-featuretypes-in-featuregroup) :

```
drawnItems
  .filter(function(layer) {
    return layer instanceof L.Marker;
  })
  .forEach(function(layer) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  });
```

Or in a shorter one-liner using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
drawnItems.getLayers().filter(l=>l instanceof L.Marker).forEach(l=>map.remove(l));
```

Remember to check the documentation for [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

On the other hand, you should consider creating several `L.FeatureGroup`s, one for each kind of layer you want to add/remove from/to the map.

Comment: thank for your help and for the useful tips. I tested the code and it generates -drawnItems.filter is not a function- error for some reason. I tried to modify but no succes..

Comment: Not "some reason". If `drawnItems` is an instance of `L.LayerGroup`, then it's not an array. OTOH, `drawnItems.getLayers()` returns an instance of `Array`, which has a `filter` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(map.hasLayer(drawnFeatures)){
    // map.removeLayer(drawnFeatures); <-- this the wrong way
    drawnFeatures.eachLayer(
        function(l){
            drawnFeatures.removeLayer(l);
    });
}
```

that can delete each layer without delete Features group. can be used again for new drawn items.